# How can I detect if my fetched email is bounced or not

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

I fetched emails from servers by using IMAP or POP3 and entered the fetched emails to database but I noticed there are a lot of bounced emails entered to the system so I searched a lot on google to check fetched email and if it's bounced email I'll  not enter it to the system and I found library BounceDetectResult to detect if email is bounced or not but this library working only with message type MimeMessage so It's useful when I use IMAP but it's not work with message type OpenPop.Mime.Message so I can't use It  when I use POP3

```
 var result= BounceDetectorMail.Detect(message);//message type MimeMessage
        if (result.IsBounce) 
        {
            em.DelivaryFailure = true;
        }
```

so my problem I didn't find way to detect if my retrieved message is bounced or not when I use pop3 in retrieving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [MailBounceDetector](https://github.com/rgl/MailBounceDetector) library that you mentioned uses my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library to detect if a message is a bounced message or not.

The good news is that you *can* use that library because I *also* have a library that does POP3 called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), so you can use that instead of OpenPOP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

For any who may need, from [Bounce inspector software library](https://www.componentpro.com/products/bounce-inspector), supports both POP3 and IMAP:

```
// POP3 server information.
const string serverName = "myserver";
const string user = "name@domain.com";
const string password = "mytestpassword";
const int port = 995;
const SecurityMode securityMode = SecurityMode.Implicit;
// Create a new instance of the Pop3Client class.
Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
Console.WriteLine("Connecting Pop3 server: {0}:{1}...", serverName, port);
// Connect to the server.
client.Connect(serverName, port, securityMode);
// Login to the server.
Console.WriteLine("Logging in as {0}...", user);
client.Authenticate(user, password);
// Initialize BounceInspector.
BounceInspector inspector = new BounceInspector();
inspector.AllowInboxDelete = false; // true if you want BounceInspector automatically delete all hard bounces.
// Register processed event handler.
inspector.Processed += inspector_Processed;
// Download messages from Pop3 Inbox to 'c:\test' and process them.
BounceResultCollection result = inspector.ProcessMessages(client, "c:\\test");
// Display processed emails.
foreach (BounceResult r in result)
{
   // If this message was identified as a bounced email message.
   if (r.Identified)
   {
       // Print out the result
       Console.Write("FileName: {0}\nSubject: {1}\nAddress: {2}\nBounce Category: {3}\nBounce Type: {4}\nDeleted: {5}\nDSN Action: {6}\nDSN Diagnostic Code: {7}\n\n",
                       System.IO.Path.GetFileName(r.FilePath),
                       r.MailMessage.Subject,
                       r.Addresses[0],
                       r.BounceCategory.Name,
                       r.BounceType.Name,
                       r.FileDeleted,
                       r.Dsn.Action,
                       r.Dsn.DiagnosticCode);
   }
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} bounced message found", result.BounceCount);
// Disconnect.
Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
client.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , but this library is not free

Comment: You can use the free trial and see if it fits you, then search for alternatives of the sort if you really want to :)

Comment: yes I see this library will achieve my requirements but I already searched about other free libraries but i didn't find any thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<bool> TestIMAPConnection([FromBody] IMAPGatewayModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
        {
            // Connect to the IMAP server
            client.Connect(model.EmailServer, int.Parse(model.InComingPort), true);
            
            // Authenticate with the provided credentials
            client.Authenticate(model.InUsername, model.InPassword);

            // Open the inbox folder
            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            // Search for unseen messages
            var unseen = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
            foreach (var uniqueId in unseen)
            {
                // Get the message details
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uniqueId);

                // Check for bounce header
                string bounceHeader = message.Headers["X-Bounce-Info"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bounceHeader))
                {
                    // If bounce detected, update the last bounce time in the model
                    Console.WriteLine("Bounce detected for email: " + model.InUsername);
                    model.LastBounceTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            
            // Disconnect from the IMAP server
            client.Disconnect(true);
            
            // Return true indicating successful connection and no bounced emails
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log any errors that occur during the process
        Console.WriteLine("Error checking email bounce: " + ex.Message);
        
        // Return false indicating failure in the IMAP connection or checking for bounced emails
        return false;
    }
}
```